# how to do zebra stripe in xslt

Tags: xslt, pdf, zebra-striping

I'm trying do zebra stripe for my pdf file. The XML like as below:

```
<root>
   <order>
      <attribute1>1</attribute1>
      <attribute2>2</attribute2>
      <attribute3>0</attribute3>
      <attribute4>4</attribute4>
      <attribute5/>
   </order>
</root>
```

The attribute3 isn't appeared if the value is '0'. Also attribute5 isn't appear if there is no value for it. So I cannot do zebra stripe like as below:

```
<fo:table-row (colored)>

   <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block>
       <xsl:text>Attribute1</xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>

   <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block>
       <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

<fo:table-row (non colored)>
   <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block>
       <xsl:text>Attribute2</xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>

   <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block>
       <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Because attribute3 and attribute5 is not always appeared in pdf file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do here, is first use **xsl:apply-templates** to select only the child nodes you wish to output (This assumes you are currently positioned on the **order** element:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[normalize-space()][. != '0']" />
```

Then you have a template to match child elements of **order** elements, like so:

Within this template, you can then output the table-row, and to do the 'coloured' attribute, you can test the 'position' of the current attribute, to see if it is odd or even:

```
<fo:table-row>
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="colour">zebra</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```

Try this XSLT as a start

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="order">
    <fo:table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[normalize-space()][. != '0']" />
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="order/*">
    <fo:table-row>
      <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
        <xsl:attribute name="colour">zebra</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously you would use the correct xsl-fo styling here, and not literally the 'colour=zebra' attribute as shown here....